# Recursive Child/Parent queries in T/SQL

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql, recursion

I am using T/SQL in Microsoft SQL Server 2008

I have a table

```
CREATE TABLE [TestTable](
[CHILD] [int] NOT NULL,
[PARENT] [int] NOT NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO
```

These are some values which define a parent child hierarchial relationship

```
CHILD PARENT
1       2
2       0
3       1
4       2
5       0
```

Visually, this table looks like this

```
0
   2
      1
         3
      4
   5
```

I would ideally like the values to be shown as follows (where the right hand column indicates the generation)

```
CHILD    GENERATION
 0          0
 2          1
 1          2
 3          3
 4          2
 5          1
```

My T/SQL code looks like this

```
with n(CHILD, PARENT, GENERATION) as (
select CHILD, PARENT,1 as GENERATION from TestTable
where PARENT=0 
union all
select nplus1.CHILD, nplus1.PARENT, GENERATION+1 from TestTable as nplus1, n
where nplus1.PARENT=n.CHILD 
)
select CHILD,GENERATION from n
```

However it doesn't work!

It returns

```
CHILD   GENERATION
2        1
5        1
1        2
4        2
3        3
```

It has the right generation, but the wrong sort order!
Does anyone have any ideas how to solve this?

Thank you!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You'll need your recursion to also build something that can be sorted by at the end:

```
declare @t TABLE (
[CHILD] [int] NOT NULL,
[PARENT] [int] NOT NULL
) 

insert @t values
( 0, -1),   -- I added this
( 1, 2 ),
( 2, 0 ),
( 3, 1 ),
( 4, 2 ),
( 5, 0 )
```

(note I have added a true root element)

```
;with n(CHILD, PARENT, GENERATION, hierarchy) as (
select CHILD, PARENT,0, CAST(CHILD as nvarchar) as GENERATION from @t
where PARENT=-1
union all
select nplus1.CHILD, nplus1.PARENT, GENERATION+1, 
cast(n.hierarchy + '.' + CAST(nplus1.child as nvarchar) as nvarchar)
 from 
@t as nplus1 inner join n on nplus1.PARENT=n.CHILD 
)
select CHILD,GENERATION
from n
order by hierarchy
```

returns

```
CHILD       GENERATION
----------- -----------
0           0
2           1
1           2
3           3
4           2
5           1
```

Including the `hierarchy` for illustration:

```
CHILD       GENERATION  hierarchy
----------- ----------- ------------------------------
0           0           0
2           1           0.2
1           2           0.2.1
3           3           0.2.1.3
4           2           0.2.4
5           1           0.5
```

Depending on how big your ids get, you might have to do stuff with left-padding with zeroes to get the sorting right.

Note that SQL 2008 has a built-in `hierarchy` type for this kind of thing...

Comment: I had a look also at http://blogs.msdn.com/b/simonince/archive/2008/10/17/hierarchies-with-hierarchyid-in-sql-2008.aspx which discusses the hierarchyID type that you mention.

Answer (score 0):

Based on AakashM's solution I'm proposing a solution that will be a bit more general, because it is using row_number to build the hierarchy 
instead of using the column values.

Here is it:

```
;with n(CHILD, PARENT, GENERATION, hierarchy) as (
select CHILD, PARENT,0, CAST(CHILD as nvarchar) as GENERATION from @t
where PARENT=-1
union all
select nplus1.CHILD, nplus1.PARENT, GENERATION+1, 
cast(hierarchy + '.' + CAST(cast(ROW_NUMBER() over (order by nplus1.CHILD) as int) as nvarchar) as nvarchar)
 from 
@t as nplus1 inner join n on nplus1.PARENT=n.CHILD 
)
select CHILD,GENERATION,hierarchy
from n
order by hierarchy
```

returns:

```
CHILD   GENERATION  hierarchy
0   0   0
2   1   0.1
1   2   0.1.1
3   3   0.1.1.1
4   2   0.1.2
5   1   0.2
```