# Storing result of recursive T/SQL query back in table

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql

I am using T/SQL in SQL Server 2008

I have a table MyTable with the following columns:

```
 CHILD
 PARENT
 HIERARCHY
```

The HIERARCHY column is currently empty, but I would like to populate it.

I have some code which creates a hierarchy ID (adapted from the code in [Recursive Child/Parent queries in T/SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9004543/recursive-child-parent-queries-in-t-sql))
This code works very nicely.

```
with n(CHILD, PARENT, GENERATION, hierarchy) as (
select CHILD, PARENT,0, CAST(CHILD as nvarchar) as GENERATION from MyTable
where PARENT=1 
union all
select nplus1.CHILD, nplus1.PARENT, GENERATION+1, 
cast(n.hierarchy + '/' + CAST(nplus1.CHILD as nvarchar) as  nvarchar)
 from 
MyTable nplus1 inner join n on nplus1.PARENT=n.CHILD and    
)
```

I can see the results of this query by doing:

```
select CHILD,GENERATION,Hierarchy from n
```

However I would like to put the result back in the column Hierarchy in MyTable. 
This code does not work!

```
update MyTable e
set HIERARCHY='/'+(select hierarchy from n where n.CHILD=e.CHILD)
```

Does anyone know how to do it? Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe something like this:

```
;with n(CHILD, PARENT, GENERATION, hierarchy) as (
select CHILD, PARENT,0, CAST(CHILD as nvarchar) as GENERATION from MyTable
where PARENT=1 
union all
select nplus1.CHILD, nplus1.PARENT, GENERATION+1, 
cast(n.hierarchy + '/' + CAST(nplus1.CHILD as nvarchar) as  nvarchar)
 from 
MyTable nplus1 inner join n on nplus1.PARENT=n.CHILD and    
)
UPDATE MyTable 
   SET Hierarchy=n.hierarchy
FROM MyTable 
JOIN n
  ON n.CHILD=MyTable.CHILD
```

**Edit**

You mean like this:

```
;with n(CHILD, PARENT, GENERATION, hierarchy) as (
select CHILD, PARENT,0, CAST(CHILD as nvarchar) as GENERATION from MyTable
where PARENT=1 
union all
select nplus1.CHILD, nplus1.PARENT, GENERATION+1, 
cast(n.hierarchy + '/' + CAST(nplus1.CHILD as nvarchar) as  nvarchar)
 from 
MyTable nplus1 inner join n on nplus1.PARENT=n.CHILD and    
)
UPDATE MyTable 
SET Hierarchy='/'+n.hierarchy+'/' 
FROM MyTable e 
JOIN n ON n.child=e.child
```

Comment: Just for completeness... Here is the exact code...UPDATE MyTable 
   SET Hierarchy='/'+n.hierarchy+'/'
FROM MyTable
JOIN n
  ON n.child=MyTable.child

Comment: Updated the answer for completeness. If you are fine with the answer you might consider accepting it :P

Comment: Of course... (I had to pop out of the office before I was allowed to accept the answer...) Thanks again!