# SQL Server - List Parent Records in Hierarchy Order

Tags: sql-server, parent-child, hierarchy, recursive-query

I have a table that is used to build a tree structure of menu items. Sample contents of this table is below:

```
Parent      Child
------      ------
190         192
192         180
180         185
185         184
190         191
191         197
197         200
```

I need a query that will give me a comma delimited list of parent records in the order they appear in the hierarchy including the child id e.g:

- Given the child id 184, it should return 190, 192, 180, 185, 184
- Given the child id 200, it should return 190, 191, 197, 200

Comment: Did you try this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9004543/recursive-child-parent-queries-in-t-sql

Comment: I don't think this can be done in a single query because you are effectively expanding a recursive relationship. I think it could be done using a stored function (I'm not sure if SQL Server supports recursion in stored functions). Assuming it is supported, you could then easily write a simple query calling the stored function.

Comment: It can definitely be done in one query (or two). If this question is is still open in a few hours, I'll provide an answer.

Comment: Assuming the difficulty comes in having the result comma delimited, is it possible to have the result in usual format (without the need for comma delimited)? I'd prefer half bread to none :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made use of a table variable for the sake of demonstration. To use a standard table, remove the `@tempTable` declaration and insert statements. Then replace the `@tempTable` references with the table name.

```
declare @childId int
set @childId = 184

declare @tempTable table(parent int, child int)

insert into @tempTable values(190, 192)
insert into @tempTable values(192, 180)
insert into @tempTable values(180, 185)
insert into @tempTable values(185, 184)
insert into @tempTable values(190, 191)
insert into @tempTable values(191, 197)
insert into @tempTable values(197, 200)

declare @currentItem int
set @currentItem = @childId

declare @output varchar(max)
set @output = cast(@currentItem as varchar)

while (exists(select 1 from @tempTable where child = @currentItem))
begin
    select 
        @currentItem = parent
    from 
        @tempTable 
    where 
        child = @currentItem

    set @output = cast(@currentItem as varchar) + ', ' + @output 
end

select @output
```

Some example output:

For 184: `190, 192, 180, 165, 184`

For 200: `190, 191, 197, 200`

Answer (score 1):

Here it is...

```
Declare @data Table
(
Parent int,
Child int
)

insert into @data values
(190, 192),
(192, 180),
(180, 185),
(185, 184),
(190, 191),
(191, 197),
(197, 200)

Declare @Id as Int = 184

/*

    CompleteData - query produce following output
        ID          ParentId
        ----------- -----------
        180         192
        184         185
        185         180
        190         NULL -- we discoverd this missing data
        191         190
        192         190
        197         191
        200         197

    ChildHierarchyData - query produce following ouput
        ID          ParentID    Level
        ----------- ----------- -----------
        184         185         0
        185         180         1
        180         192         2
        192         190         3
        190         NULL        4

    Concatinated - query conact all ID from above result
*/

;with CompleteData
as
(
    Select Child ID, Parent ParentId from @data
    UNION
    Select Child.Parent Id, Parent.Parent ParentId From @data   Child
        Left Outer Join @data Parent
            on Child.Parent = parent.Child
    WHERE
        parent.Parent IS NULL

),
ChildHierarchyData(ID,ParentID, Level)
as
(
    Select ID,ParentID, 0 as Level from CompleteData Where ID = @Id
    union all
    Select CompleteData.ID, CompleteData.ParentID, ChildHierarchyData.Level +1 from CompleteData 
        INNER Join ChildHierarchyData
            on ChildHierarchyData.ParentID = CompleteData.ID
),
Concatinated(result)
as
(
    Select Cast((select Cast(ID  as nvarchar) + ',' [data()] from ChildHierarchyData Order By Level Desc FOR XML Path('')) as Nvarchar(max))
)
select Left(result, len(result)-1) as Result from Concatinated
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need comma-separated list, it's easy to do with recursive cte:

```
with cte as (
    select
        t.Parent, 1 as Level,
        cast(t.Parent as nvarchar(max)) + ',' + cast(t.Child as nvarchar(max)) as Path
    from Table1 as t
    where t.Child = @Child

    union all

    select
        t.Parent, Level + 1 as Level,
        cast(t.Parent as nvarchar(max)) + ',' + c.Path as Path
    from Table1 as t
        inner join cte as c on c.Parent = t.Child
)
select top 1 Path
from cte
order by Level desc
```

**<kbd>[sql fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/034118/1)</kbd>**