# SQL Server update within recursive query

Tags: sql-server-2008, recursion, sql-update, common-table-expression

I am using Microsoft SQL Server 2008 and trying to accomplish something very similar to this post using a recursive query: [Recursive Child/Parent queries in T/SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9004543/recursive-child-parent-queries-in-t-sql)

Naturally I've attempted to simplify things; hopefully I have done so in a clear manner. My table looks something like this:

```
Parent  Child
A       A
A       B
B       D
D       H
D       I
A       C
C       E
E       C
E       J
E       K
C       F
C       G
```

Visually the relationships would look like this:

```
A
    B
        D
            H
            I
    C
        E
            C
            J
            K
        F
        G
```

I need to create a new column in the table that represents a child entity's path to the top level (A in this case):

```
Parent  Child  Chain
A       A      A
A       B      A,B
B       D      A,B,D
D       H      A,B,D,H
D       I      A,B,D,I
A       C      A,C
C       E      A,C,E
E       C      A,C,E,C
E       J      A,C,E,J
E       K      A,C,E,K
C       F      A,C,F
C       G      A,C,G
```

The wrinkle in this, and the reason parent-child may not be the terms to use here can be seen with entity C, which is both a parent and a child to entity E, which results in an endless recursive loop.

My thought is to update the chain value within the recursive loop and limit recursive calls to entities with a NULL value in the chain column. The idea is to recurse an entity only the first time it is encountered. What I have won't work and I'm not sure how to integrate the update into the recursive call:

```
WITH r(parent,child,mychain)
AS
(
    SELECT parent, child, child AS myChain 
    FROM myTable 
    WHERE parent = 'A' AND
    parent &#60;&#62; child AND
    chain IS NULL
    UNION ALL
    SELECT v.parent, v.child, myChain + ',' + v.child AS myChain 
    FROM myTable v
    INNER JOIN r ON r.child = v.parent
    WHERE v.parent &#60;&#62; v.child
)
UPDATE myTable
SET chain = r.myChain
FROM myTable AS c
JOIN r ON c.ID = r.ID
```

Any suggestions on how I can accomplish this?

Thanks in advance.

**Edit:**

It may be I've oversimplified a little. Because the actual values for the parent and child columns are quite long (in the neighborhood of 20+ characters) I really need to create a chain using the record ids as ooposed to the values. I've modified Simon's suggestion as shown below. This gets me pretty close; however, the C -> E record does not get output (all records should eventually get updated with the chain). It may not matter; I'm still trying to work through it.

```
with r as
(
    SELECT id, parent, child, 
      CAST( id AS VARCHAR(1024) ) AS CHAIN,
      0 as level
    FROM myTable 
    WHERE id = '1' 


    UNION ALL
    SELECT c.id, c.parent, c.child, 
      cast( (r.CHAIN + ',' + CAST( c.id AS varchar(10)) ) AS varchar(1024)) AS CHAIN,
      r.level + 1 as level
    FROM myTable c
    JOIN r
      ON r.child = c.parent
    WHERE c.parent != c.child AND r.parent != c.child

)
select * from r order by r.level, r.parent, r.child;
```

Comment: See below. Does that work for you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
with r as
(
    SELECT parent, child, 
      CAST( (parent + ',' + child) AS VARCHAR(10)) AS chain, 
      0 as level
    FROM myTable 
    WHERE parent = 'A' 
    AND parent != child

    UNION ALL
    SELECT c.parent, c.child, 
      cast((r.chain + ',' + c.child) as varchar(10)) AS chain, 
      r.level + 1 as level
    FROM myTable c
    JOIN r
      ON r.child = c.parent
    WHERE r.chain NOT LIKE '%,' + c.child + ',%'

)
select * 
from r 
order by r.level, r.parent, r.child;
```

Check out on: [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/beb255/3)

Comment: You can probably remove the casts. SQL fiddle seemed to need them, but I don't think sql server does.

Comment: Simon, thanks for the response. I think you're getting me close. I've successfully run this against my real data on some top level entities but I have others timing out after hitting the limit I set of 5000 recursions. I'm still working on figuring out if hitting that limit should make any sense.

Comment: You must have deeper cycles then. The above code prevent cycles like c=>e=>c with the "WHERE c.parent != c.child AND r.parent != c.child"

Comment: Added check for any cycle length. I thought you just needed the simpler use case.

Comment: It does work and it answers the original question so I'm going to mark this as answered. I'd note though that I couldn't get it to work building the chain using the ID instead of the child values (since we have the child value but not its ID when the chain is appended). Thanks for your help Simon!