# Finding all Children in a Hierarchy SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a Database Hierarchy that sits somewhat like this

```
LHID | location     | parent
------------------------------
1    | Trim         | NULL
2    | Trim - South | Trim
3    | South-1      | Trim - South
```

What I need to do is select all children of Trim - South. It goes extremely deep and there are around 100 children locations and I've found ways to do it recursively but have had no luck replicating them. I know the logic of going through recursively to select all the children as I have done similar procedures in other languages, just never with SQL so I'm having trouble grasping the exact necessary syntax for it. Any ideas?

Comment: Can you post a more relevant sample data?, in the one posted, the result is only one row. You could also post it in [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com)

Comment: You probably are looking for a recursive cte. http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186243.aspx

Comment: So you are looking at Parent Column Trim - South and expect  the Trim - South from location column?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Recursive Child/Parent queries in T/SQL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9004543/recursive-child-parent-queries-in-t-sql)

Comment: You already have an answer, but might I suggest changing your schema to refer to the parent's LHID rather than location? When you do it this way, you can have a self-referential foreign key (to make sure you don't orphan any records) and you can change the location's name without having to update children.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a recursive CTE:

```
WITH CTE 
AS(
  SELECT 1 AS relationLevel, child.*
  FROM dbo.TableName child
  WHERE child.parent = 'Trim - South'

  UNION ALL

  SELECT relationLevel+1, parent.*
  FROM CTE nextOne
  INNER JOIN  dbo.TableName parent ON parent.parent = nextOne.location
)
SELECT * FROM CTE ORDER BY relationLevel
```

Result:

```
RELATIONLEVEL   LHID    LOCATION    PARENT
1                3      South-1     Trim - South
1                4      South-2     Trim - South
2                4      South-2-1   South-2
```

<kbd>**[DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/102ac/2/0)**</kbd>

Maybe you want to travserse from the parent to the children, then use this:

```
WITH CTE 
AS(
  SELECT 1 AS relationLevel, parent.*
  FROM dbo.TableName parent
  WHERE parent.location = 'Trim - South'  

  UNION ALL

  SELECT relationLevel + 1, child.*
  FROM CTE nextOne
  INNER JOIN  dbo.TableName child ON child.parent = nextOne.location
)   
SELECT * FROM CTE ORDER BY relationLevel
```

Result:

```
RELATIONLEVEL   LHID    LOCATION    PARENT
1               2    Trim - South   Trim
2               3    South-1        Trim - South
2               4    South-2        Trim - South
3               4    South-2-1      South-2
```

<kbd>[**DEMO**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/102ac/3/0)</kbd>

Comment: This worked perfectly. Thanks! I walked through the procedure and it makes a lot more sense now.

Comment: @todaroa: i've edited my answer to show the other way(from  parent to children).