# Recursive Manager/Associate query in T/SQL

Tags: t-sql, recursive-query

looking at this example [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9004543/recursive-child-parent-queries-in-t-sql)

I want to be able to walk through an HR table that I populate with who the manager is that is looking up themself and their reports (which shows them what level they are also)

Data:

```
    AssociateID     AssociateName    ManagerID    AssociateTitle
    ===========     =============    =========    ==============
    1               Jack Frost                    Chief Executive Officer
    2               Cindy Smith      1            President of Sales
    3               William Howard   1            President of Technology
    4               Ben Samson       2            Director of Tradeshow
    5               Sarah Jones      2            Director of Documentation
    6               Laurie Ralph     4            Manager
    7               Tina Nelson      5            Manager
    8               Joe May          6            Coordinator
    9               Peter Gill       7            Coordinator
   10               Kelly Kraft      2            Director of Facilities
   11               Heidi Trump      8            Administrative Assistant
```

If CEO signs in he gets the following data:

```
Jack Frost
 Cindy Smith
  Ben Samson
   Laurie Ralph
    Joe May
     Heidi Trump
 William Howard
```

But if Cindy Smith signs in her list would be:

```
 Cindy Smith
  Ben Samson
   Laurie Ralph
    Joe May
     Heidi Trump
```

The indenting is for visual.  I was also wondering if there could be a column that indicates what level the people are below.  Level 1; Level 2; etc

And if a person who signs in (example: Heidi Trump) her list is only her name.

Is this possible with TSQL?

Answer (score 0):

I have it and want to share:

```
DECLARE @Associate float 
Set @Associate = 1

;
WITH DirectReports(ManagerID, EmployeeID, Associate, Title, EmployeeLevel) AS   
(  
    SELECT ManagerID, AssociateID, LegalLastName + ', ' + LegalFirstName, Title, 1 AS EmployeeLevel  
    FROM AssociateMaster 
    WHERE 
        ManagerID = @Associate

    UNION ALL  

    SELECT e.ManagerID, e.AssociateID, e.LegalLastName + ', ' + e.LegalFirstName, e.Title, EmployeeLevel + 1  
    FROM dbo.AssociateMaster AS e  
        INNER JOIN DirectReports AS d  
        ON e.ManagerID = d.EmployeeID  
)  

SELECT 
  DR.ManagerID, MGR.LegalLastName + ', ' + MGR.LegalFirstName AS AssociateName, DR.EmployeeID, DR.Associate, DR.Title, DR.EmployeeLevel   
FROM DirectReports DR
  INNER JOIN AssociateMaster as Mgr ON DR.ManagerID = Mgr.AssociateID

UNION

SELECT ' ', ' ', AssociateID, LegalLastName + ', ' + LegalFirstName, Title, 0  
FROM AssociateMaster 
WHERE 
    AssociateID = @Associate

ORDER BY 
  DR.EmployeeLevel Asc, 
  MGR.LegalLastName + ', ' + MGR.LegalFirstName ASC,
  DR.Associate Asc

OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0);
```